# Pigeonhole principle for proof

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Prove that if *a* is a natural number, then there exists two unequal natural numbers *k* and *l* for which 
$$
a^k - a^l 
$$
is divisible by 10.

I'm strangely lost on this one. I understand the pigeonhole principle but I'm unsure how to apply it here. Any help is greatly aprpeciated.

Comment: There are infinitely many natural numbers and there are only 10 possibilities for the last digit. And $\infty > 10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider the possible last digits of powers of $a$. There are at most how many different possibilities?

Comment: There are 10. 0,1,....9. How do I use the pigeonhole principle to express this in a proof?

Comment: @beachtowel: Show that you must be able to find two different powers of $a$ with the same last digit. What happens when you take their difference?

Comment: When you take their difference it becomes a number divisible by 10, right?  I'm confused as to how to show the two powers of _a_  with the same last digit.

Comment: @beachtowel: Yes to the first question. For the second, use the pigeonhole principle. There are at most ten possible last digits. Surely there are more than ten different powers of $a$ ...

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. So, using the pigeon principle, I would put the powers of _a_ (which is infinite) in let's say set A, and then the number of powers of _a_ with the same last digit into let's say set B. Since |A| > |B|, it's not injective, and therefore, there exists some _k_ and _l_ that are divisible by 10. Is that accurate?

Comment: @beachtowel: You’re making it much too hard. Just look at the set $\{a,a^2,a^3,\ldots,a^{11}\}$; it has $11$ members, and there are at most $10$ possible last digits, so ... ?

Comment: So using the pigeon hole example, there's 2 pigeons in one hole. Right? Sorry for the elaboration, I'm friend after a long day, please explain like I'm five. Haha.

Comment: @beachtowel: Think of each possible last digit as a hole. You have at most $10$ holes, but you have $11$ numbers in the set to put into those holes. Therefore?

Comment: Therefore two numbers in one hole. I got that. It's really just that simple?

Comment: @beachtowel: It’s really just that simple, once you realize that you just need two powers of $a$ with the same last digit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: @beachtowel: You’re welcome.